# Set up Daily task to import flat file to existing table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, file, import, flat

here is my newbie to SQL Server Problem.

1. I created a table with a flat file (.txt) using the Import and Export Data Wizard.
2. In order to use this table in Arc SDE, I had to create another field named ObjectID.

Need to do the following:

1. Use the daily generated flat file and erase data from table and replace with new data.
2. ObjectID field is derived and not in flat file, but need it to stay in table and autopopulate.
3. Develop script or sql statement
4. Set up daily process
5. provide error or completed reports.

Comment: I have tried to save an .sql statement that deletes the rows in the existing table and then appends the new flat file to the table but since the flat file does not contain the ObjectID field, it does not work, comes back with an error saying number of columns is incorrect.

Comment: You'd normally load the text file into a staging table that has the exact same columns as the file.  After the load is complete, you can copy the rows to the "real" table.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, I would use an Integration Services package executed as part of a Sql Server Scheduled Task. Those are the two primary technologies involved, and that should get you started.

Comment: OK, I am having trouble writing the sql statement that would delete the rows from the table and then import the new flat file

Answer (score 0):

you can use ssis technologie (Business Intelligence Development Studio) BIDS, it allows you 
to integrate your text file in your sql server table with tranformation you want (adding Object ID field )

a sample :http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3832386/Flat-File-Imports-with-SQL-Server-Integration-Services-2008.htm

make a schedule task using a sql agent

a sample here :http://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2008/09/17/scheduling-ssis-packages-with-sql-server-agent/

Comment: another newbie question, I followed the first link, but I do not have access to BIDS?  Do I have to have system admin install it?

Comment: yes BIDS is included on sql server 2005/2008 you have to install it http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/204/business-intelligence-development-studio-bids/